# Team City - build runner on static sites

Tags: teamcity

I was wondering if someone would be able to explain what Build runners do and also what i would need to use for just a static HTML / CSS / JS site, or even an already compiled .NET site.

I will be hooking up each project to its equiv SVN and grabbing updates from there, but not 100% sure what the build runners do or which i should use as technically i dont need to build the site.

Sorry it may be too much to answer but i am just struggling to get my head round Team City

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Build runners](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Runner) are just a process for a specific task, for example the MSBuild runner is set up by putting information into specific fields which it then uses to call MSBuild on the target build agent. You could just as easily use the `Command Line` runner and build up the MSBuild run command manually.

> Build runner is a part of TeamCity that allows integration with a
>   specific build tool (Ant, MSBuild, Command line, etc.). In a build
>   configuration, the build runner defines how to run a build and report
>   its results. Each build runner has two parts:
>
> - server-side settings that are configured through the web UI
> - agent-side part that executes a build on agent

You need to choose your runner depending on the task that you want to do and the technology that you have wrapped your project in. If there is no runner for your specific task then you can use the lowest common denominator which would be the `Command Line` runner.

[image: Command Line runner]

The way I approach this would be to see how I can achieve what I want to from my own environment be that calling a rake, MSBuild or batch file. I then see how I can then apply that to a tool. Do not create a process around a tool but choose a tool that fits to your process.

Comment: perfect mate, i think cmd line is the best for me then, thank you